# Cassandra export/forward data only once

Tags: cassandra, forward, data-export

I have the requirement to forward data at certain intervals from my system to an external system. To do this, I already stored all rows in a table. Already forwarded data should not be exported again.

The idea is to memorize the last export time on client side and export the following records the next time. Old rows are deleted after a successful export.

```
CREATE TABLE export(
    id int,
    import_date_time timestamp, 
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, import_date_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (import_date_time DESC) 

insert into export(id, import_date_time, data) values (1, toUnixTimestamp(now()), 'content')

select * from export where id = 1 and import_date_time > '2017-03-30 16:22:37'

delete from export where id = 1 and import_date_time <= '2017-03-30 16:22:37'
```

1. Has anyone already implemented similar or do you have a different
   solution?
2. If possible, I do not need an id for the request because I want to
       export all data

Comment: What is the approximate interval between two export ?

Comment: approximately 10 minutes, actually we think cassandra is not the best place for these data.

Answer (score 1):

If you used fixed partition key value (id = 1), then all the insert, select and delete will happen on a same node (If RF=1) over and over. And also for every delete cassandra create a tombstone entry, when you execute select query cassandra needs to merge each entry. So your select query performance will degrade.

So instead of having fixed value, use dynamic value like the below one :

```
CREATE TABLE export(
    hour int,
    day int,
    month int,
    year int,
    import_date_time timestamp, 
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((hour, day, month, year), import_date_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (import_date_time DESC);
```

Here you can insert the value of hour, day, month, year extracted from `import_date_time`

You need to take care of two case When selecting data :

1. Previous export time and current export time both at same hour.
2. Both time are not inside same hour.

For case one you need only one query and for case two you have to execute two query.

Example Query :

```
SELECT * FROM export WHERE hour = 16 AND day = 30 AND month = 3 AND year = 2017 AND import_date_time > '2017-03-30 16:22:37';
```

Comment: I'm aware of the partition problem with only id for partitioning. This shouldn't be a big problem. My main focus is to shrink the number of request, because i query all data every time (this seems not to fit to cassandra because of the partitioning)

Comment: if you specify hour,day,month and year you remain with only small amount of data.

Comment: But i have to set these values (hour, day ...) in my requests and the import timestamp is not known. The number of requests will grow and as i said... i need every time nearly all data. Why should i request thousands of requests and merge response bit by bit. For me this doesn't feel good.